# Can I run an ATX power supply close to full load, for a long time?

Tags: power-supply, power, atx

Ive been told that it is good to follow "80% rule" when using ATX power supplies, but for server supplies I can nearly max out no problem.

Ive been wanting to use a Corsair 1200W power supply (platinum) for my machine learning server, because it is already installed, but I added another 3090. It will most likely be doing a lot of deep learning months at a time. It will be running at 1130W, about 1300W from the wall.

Is this a mistake?

Nowhere in the manual has the corsair psu said I shouldnt be running at close to maxload for a very long time. It also has a 10 year warranty, which makes it confusing even more.

Comment: If it is rated for X watts, why would it could not be used for X watts? Where would this 80% rule come from?

Comment: If you run it hotter, some components will die earlier (fans, electrolytic capacitors). How much earlier will depend on what the manufacturer put on your device. Probably the best you can do is to run it well ventilated. As in, make sure your power supply isnt the part removing the hot air from the GPUs and so on.

Comment: My gut feeling would be that efficiency would drop off near the top of the rating.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fudge factor that people use automatically without thinking because ratings can be ambiguous and poorly standardized, at least in the consumer market.

This marketing practice is usually less blatant in critical industries or applications.

Sometimes, it requires digging into the documentation to determine what they mean.

If a power supply is designed to operate continuously at the nameplate rating for 10 yrs, and the MFG stands behind that with a warranty.  I would take that to the bank.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you base your calculations on the peak power consumption of the various components - that is a good number to use, but leads to quite an overkill power supply.

If the peak power is below the max power that your supply can deliver, it will work. Keep in mind that the heat will make all your components age faster.

In this particular case, if you notice any instability on the system, you can always throttle your cards, reducing their power consumption, and still get a stable system without spending a dime.